# Filtering records in MongoDB using a date value

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In a MongoDB collection i have a record as follows :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d0d3945e69a56cf504375b7"), "action" : "Click", "dt" : "Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)","url":"http://www.google.com"}
```

If i search using `db.mycollection.find({url:'http://www.google.com'})`,the record **shows up**, but if i search by the date parameter using `db.mycollection.find({dt:'Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)'})` the record **does not show up**.

What is wrong about command `db.mycollection.find({dt:'Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)'})` ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Rule of thumb, post examples of the ACTUAL data that REPRODUCE your problem. Posting an example with a string field while you have an UTC date field in the actual data is not very productive.

Comment: Looks like op has actually used string field. :) That might be the reason he is not able to use find properly.

Answer (score 2):

It does work :

```
> db.test.save({ "_id" : ObjectId("4d0d3945e69a56cf504375b7"), "action" : "Click", "dt" : "Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)","url":"http://www.google.com"})
> db.test.find({dt:'Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d0d3945e69a56cf504375b7"), "action" : "Click", "dt" : "Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "url" : "http://www.google.com" }
```

Generally you'll want to save dates as dates rather than strings though.

Comment: You're storing it as a string. Querying by date from the shell is done through dt: ISODate(yourDate)