# Date object in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In a collection in my MondoDB database i have a collection like follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d0d3945e69a56cf504375b7"), "action" : "Click", "dt" : "Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)"}
```

**dt is a Date object**. If i do `db.mycollection.find({action:"Click"})`the record comes up. But `db.mycollection.find({dt:'Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)'})`does not show any records, since i guess dt is a Date object.

How to query by dt in the above case ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898039/filtering-records-in-mongodb-using-a-date-value. In the future, edit your own question rather than spamming please.

Comment: omg what a bad idea storing date in that format ... can't you use 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycollection.find({dt:ISODate('Sun Dec 19 2010 03:44:21 GMT+0000 (UTC)')})
```